# How to find Events function shape easily in Avalonia Ui?

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, avalonia

as someone who's a b*e*ginner in avalonia ui and with a little expirience in wpf I found it hard to know how the event's function should be written in avalonia ui without any help (wpf handles that for you automaticly)

do you have any idea on how to know that easily without having to remember them all ?

Comment: What IDE are you using? Visual Studio/Rider should offer you with some options for each control ~ a.k.a. which events and properties each object has. Otherwise, when we are writing software, we're usually having some results in mind. E.g. if user press the button, this grid will show and will be filled with data. Then we are looking for solutions like "how to handle button press in Avalonia UI" or "how to make grid visible in Avalonia UI". And you will get your results. Last (not least), read [the docs](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/).

Comment: Thanks , I am using visual studio but when I tryed wpf it helped me by creating the event function in the code behind automaticly when I am writing the event in xaml .is this feature available in avalonia ?